# SiwiftUI: UITextView is switching to TextKit 1

Tags: swiftui, uitextview, ios16, textkit

I got the log message **UITextView is switching to TextKit 1 compatibility mode because its textStorage contains attributes which are not compatible with TextKit 2** by using `documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html` for a NSAttributedString.

*Example:*

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView()
    return textView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context _: Context) {
    var currentText: NSAttributedString?
    let htmlString = "<html><body><h1>Example</h1></body></html>"
    
    guard let encodedData = htmlString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        fatalError("Could not encode HTML data")
    }
    
    do {
        currentText = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData,
                                             options: [
                                                .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
                                             ],
                                             documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    } catch {
        fatalError("error")
    }
    
    uiView.attributedText = currentText
}
```

Is there any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Do you need to fix it? TextKit 1 is still more fully featured and bug free than TextKit 2 at this time.

Comment: @AmyWorrall TextKit 1 is still fine. But is there any way to force use TextKit 1 and avoid the log message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You can choose TextKit 1 or TextKit 2.

In iOS 16+, by default `UITextView` uses `TextKit 2`. If you want to use `TextKit 1`, construct the `UITextView` using this constructor:

```
init(usingTextLayoutManager: Bool)
```

> Creates a new text view, with or without a text layout manager depending on the Boolean value you specify.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview

If `usingTextLayoutManager` is true, `UITextView` uses `TextKit 2`. If it is `false`, `TextKit 1` will be used.

#### TextKit 2

```
let textView = UITextView(usingTextLayoutManager: true)
```

#### TextKit 1

```
let textView = UITextView(usingTextLayoutManager: false)
```

---

*It is the same in `NSTextView` also.*